# Why isnt this writing to a file in ruby

Tags: ruby

Very new to ruby. I'm trying to see if I can write html using ruby. Very basic script. No errors but nothing is written to the file and I can't figure out why. If I use `puts` after `mypage` I can see the html written to the console

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby

class MyPage
  attr_accessor :para, :startbuff


      def initialize

        @para = "<p>"
        @startbuff = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />
    <title>Your Website</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>"


      end

      def makePage
        puts @startbuff
      end

  end

    mypage = MyPage.new

    File.open("/Users/me/Desktop/MyRubyHTML.html", "w+").each { |file|  
      puts mypage.makePage
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`puts` outputs to the console, you need to do this instead:

```
def makepage
  @startbuff
end
```

this returns whatever is in `@startbuff` and then:

```
File.open("/Users/me/Desktop/MyRubyHTML.html", "w+") { |file|  file.write(mypage.makepage) }
```

Comment: Actually the problem was the .each which I didn't need. Found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833887/file-open-and-blocks-in-ruby-1-8-7

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice, that you never actually **used** your filehandle? No wonder, that nothing gets written to the file. Try

```
 file.puts(....)
```